# How do I disable Windows reboot regardless of install state?

Tags: windows, batch-file, restart

I am currently writing a batch file that, among other things, performs an unattended install of .net, IIS, MSSQL, MSSQL SP2, flash, installs some proprietary software, and lastly makes a ton of environment changes on a Windows server 2008 or 2012 platform.  All of this is done in one shot.

The script works awesome except in one situation: if Windows is in a partially updated state, perhaps needing a reboot, .net or IIS will force me to reboot regardless of whether I have the `/norestart` switch to DISM or not.

Is there a way to, within the batch file, disable any need for a reboot to the point that DISM and/or SQL install will not ask or require it?  Or, less favorable, the means to determine from a batch file if a reboot is needed?  I don't like it but I could do a check and force a `shutdown -r` if needed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Different programs detect the necessity to restart OS differently, one of the most popular methods is checking `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` -> `PendingFileRenameOperations` value.

```
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" /v PendingFileRenameOperations >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo OK
    ....proceed with stuff
) else (
    echo Restart is required
    pause
    exit
)
```

Although you can temporarily delete this value after dumping its contents to a reg file and later reimporting but this is very likely to break your system unless you combine the old contents with the freshly added one in historic sequence (the old, the new, maintaining versions and stuff), which would require a vbs or powershell code or some utility.